# Android Wear 2.0 GoogleApiClient fails to connect due to Invalid Account error

Tags: android, wear-os

I am currently developing an Android Wear 2.0 application making use of the Google Fit APIs. I am finding that my google api client always fails to connect. The error displayed is:

"Invalid Account error: An invalid account was specified when connecting. Please provide a valid account."

It appears to be by adding the scope addScope() method causes this to occur. Without this line, the google api client will connect, but obviously cannot be used appropriately without the scope.

```
googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addApi(Wearable.API)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Fitness.SENSORS_API)
    .addScope(new Scope(Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ))
    .build();
googleApiClient.connect();
```

I have enabled the Google Fit Api on the google developer console and the OAuth 2.0 client IDs. I have enabled permissions on the device itself. I cannot determine what causes this issue, or how to sort it. I have followed the example sample code from the developers site to a T.

app manifest

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.project.androidfitnessapp" >
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.permission.PROVIDE_BACKGROUND" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.javapapers.android.maps.path.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BODY_SENSORS" />

    <uses-feature
        android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
        android:required="true" />

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.type.watch" />

    <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Material" >

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.wearable.standalone"
        android:value="true" />
    <activity
        ...
```

the build script

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.project.androidfitnessapp"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
} 
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0'
    provided 'com.google.android.wearable:wearable:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-wearable:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.0'
    compile 'com.jjoe64:graphview:4.2.1'
}
```

Comment: install or update latest version google play services in your device

Comment: Can you post your Wear app's manifest?

Comment: added update with build script and manifest. I am running this in an emulator with Google APIs enabled

Comment: Need we ask if you've set up a valid Google account on the emulator? I would also speculate that Fit APIs may not work correctly on an emulator that has no biometric interfaces; are you sure that those are indeed being emulated?

Comment: The emulator is connected to a real device (mobile phone), and pulls the correct Google account from that. So that shouldn't be an issue. I am never getting far enough to emulate the biometric data because the google api client never connects successfully. The api client is built in the onCreate method of the activity, and fails from there.

Comment: Can you confirm that the Google account details are synced from the phone? For example, by opening Play store on the emulator and making sure it knows about your purchased apps. Also, my point about the biometric aspect is that if it's missing from an emulator (and I don't know for sure one way or the other), you may be unable to even connect to the API. Again, I don't know for sure, but that wouldn't surprise me.

Comment: yeah the play store on the emulator allows me to install purchased apps from my phone etc. All works fine. The Google Fit app downloads to the emulator and works as expected. I can't image that having an Android Wear device is absolutely necessary to develop with the google fit APIs. Must be something else I am missing here but am pretty stumped by it.

Comment: Do you need to specify the Google Fit API key in the manifest? I haven't seen it in any examples.

Comment: Did you happen to solve this? If so, how?